# Strategy to import a raw dataset into a database with multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, psql

I have a set of [AIS data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) in a single table. The data is based on a ships position, as in **latitude** and **longitude** together with a lot of static information such as an **identifier**, **length**, **width**, **name** and such But to increase efficiency and decrease redundancy I need to split this table into multiple (5) tables (in form of a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)).

My question is what is the best strategy to go on about this?
My ideas are:

- Remove the FK constraints and insert the distinct information into the dimension tables and then later look at how to populate the fact table to connect the dimension tables.
- Write a giant SQL query
- Write a script / program that might be able to handle this

Example of the data with limited columns:
[image: Example of the data with limited columns]

The schema of the database shows the star schema on the left and the raw data on the right.
[image: The schema of the database]

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am oversimplifying your use case, but why don't you just 1) create the dimension tables using distinct queries(generating ids in case there isn't any), 2) create the fact table with the proper constraints and 3) populate the fact table based on the original and the dimension tables with the new ids, for instance:

Data Sample:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ais_data (
  ship_name TEXT,
  lat NUMERIC,
  lon NUMERIC,
  tmstp TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO ais_data VALUES
('foo',1,2,'2021-02-19 12:10:25'),
('foo',1,3,'2021-02-19 12:20:25'),
('foo',1,4,'2021-02-19 12:30:25'),
('bar',1,2,'2021-02-19 12:10:25'),
('bar',1,4,'2021-02-19 12:30:25');
```

Creating dimensions

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ship_dim (
  ship_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ship_name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO ship_dim (ship_name)
SELECT DISTINCT ship_name FROM ais_data;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE position_dim (
  position_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  lon NUMERIC, lat NUMERIC,
  geom GEOMETRY(POINT,4326),
  tmstp TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO position_dim (lon,lat,tmstp,geom)
SELECT DISTINCT lon,lat,tmstp,ST_MakePoint(lon,lat) 
FROM ais_data;
```

Creating fact table ...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data_point_fact (
  ship_id INT REFERENCES ship_dim(ship_id),
  position_id INT REFERENCES position_dim(position_id)
);
```

... and populating it

```
INSERT INTO data_point_fact 
SELECT s.ship_id,p.position_id FROM ais_data a
JOIN ship_dim s ON s.ship_name = a.ship_name
JOIN position_dim p ON p.lon = a.lon AND p.lat = a.lat AND p.tmstp = a.tmstp;


SELECT * FROM data_point_fact;

 ship_id | position_id 
---------+-------------
       1 |           3
       1 |           1
       2 |           3
       2 |           2
       2 |           1
```

See this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e8317c3ded0638fef01576d7062ad07d) (without geometry)